# Insert a grid line when the record gets saved

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to add a new record to a grid during the persist logic. However, even though the record does get added to the grid in the UI, when the page gets refreshed, the new line disappears. It is not getting persisted in the DB.

I am using the **Bills** page as reference.

**Code sample**

```
protected virtual void APTran_RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    APInvoice invoiceRow = this.Base.Document.Current;

    if (invoiceRow != null)
    {

        APTran tranRow = new APTran();
        tranRow = this.Base.Transactions.Insert(tranRow);

        tranRow.InventoryID = 10043;
        this.Base.Transactions.Update(tranRow);

        tranRow.Qty = 3;
        this.Base.Transactions.Update(tranRow);
    }
}
```

Result after saving - Record is shown in the grid:
[image]

Result after cancelling - Record disappears from the grid:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this I tend to override the Persist method and insert or update related records before calling base persist. Here is a possible example which goes inside your graph extension:

```
[PXOverride]
public virtual void Persist(Action del)
{
    foreach(APInvoice invoiceRow in Base.Document.Cache.Inserted)
    {
        APTran tranRow = this.Base.Transactions.Insert();

        tranRow.InventoryID = 10043;
        tranRow = this.Base.Transactions.Update(tranRow);

        tranRow.Qty = 3;
        this.Base.Transactions.Update(tranRow);
    }

    del?.Invoke();
}
```